# Ansible GITEA server , API call to create multiple repos for 2 users, 1 for Superadmin gitea account and the other for the git standard account

Tags: docker, ansible, gitea

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for your support, I wanna create 1 API call to create 2 repos, 1 assigned to a Superadmin gitea account and the other for standard gitea user named gitea, I assume this would need to be with a list of users in variables and a list of repos in variables also using with_items but I don't seem to get it, down I'm attaching my API call format in Ansible to achieve 1 repo/1user, please someone help:

```
- name: "gitea - Create repo"
  uri: 
    url: '{{ gitea_api_url }}/user/repos'
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    status_code: 201
    headers:
      Authorization: token {{ saved_tokens if token_ is undefined else token_ }}
    body:
      auto_init: true
      default_branch: "main"
      description: "hi"
      gitignores: ""
      issue_labels: ""
      license: ""
      name: "{{ item }}"
      private: true
      readme: ""
      template: true
      trust_model: "default"
      owner: '{{ gitea.users }}'
  with_items: "{{ repo_names }}"
  register: _repostatus
```

I only assume it could work with a list of 2 users and a list of 2 repo names using somehow with_items and conditionals together, in this case I have the following:

```
gitea:
  users: 
    - name: '{{ gitea_admin_account }}'
      admin: true
    - name: '{{ gitea_standard_account }}'
      admin: false


repo_names:
  - test2
  - test3
```

How to use the 'admin' flag to create 'test2' to the admin and 'test3' to the standard user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see an `owner` key in the Gitea API for `[POST] /user/repos`, only in the 201 response.

If you want to add other users besides the repository owner, you should probably use `[PUT] /repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators/{collaborator}` or similar after creating the repository.

For this request you can loop by using `loop` keyword:

```yaml
- name: "gitea - Add collaborators to total repo_list"
  uri: 
    url: '{{ gitea_api_url }}/repos/{{ repo_owner }}/{{ item.0 }}/collaborators/{{ item.1.name }}'
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    status_code: 204
    headers:
      Authorization: token {{ saved_tokens if token_ is undefined else token_ }}
    body:
      permission: "{{ 'admin_permission_str' if item.1.admin else 'regular_permission_str' }}"
  loop: "{{ repo_names | product(gitea.users) }}"
  register: _repostatus
```

To iterate over two lists you have to create a cartesian product of them to bring both into one data structure. Then you can iterate over this one data structure. The `{ repo_names | product(gitea.users) }}` results in the following data structure:

```
[
  [
    "test2",
    {
        "admin": true,
        "name": "gitea_admin_account"
    }
  ],
  [
    "test2",
    {
        "admin": false,
        "name": "gitea_standard_account"
    }
  ],
  [
    "test3",
    {
        "admin": true,
        "name": "gitea_admin_account"
    }
  ],
  [
    "test3",
    {
        "admin": false,
        "name": "gitea_standard_account"
    }
  ]
]
```

You can use `.0` and `.1` to address the repository name or the users dict, respectively.

Alternatively you can work with `with_nested`/`with_cartesian` instead of using `loop` directly, you can find more about this in the [Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian). But this is not necessary if you use `loop` as described above.

Comment: Many many thanks !!! Wish you all the best!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I am very happy if I could help you with my answer. You have accepted my answer. It would be nice if you would also vote for my answer. Thank you. | You can find a more detailed description in the [SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).